# Multi-client server

Tags: python, sockets

I read a little bit about using select function instead of using threads but I can't understand how to use it in my code.

EDIT:
I tried to run the following code, the program prints "Client connected", but the problem is that it doesn't print "WORKING" which means it will not send data to the client..What's wrong with my code?

```
import socket
import select

SERVER_PORT = 3000
SERVER_IP = "127.0.0.1"
MESSAGE_START = 3


CONNECTION_LIST = []

server_sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
server_sock.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
server_sock.bind((SERVER_IP, SERVER_PORT))
server_sock.listen(10)
CONNECTION_LIST.append(server_sock)

def broadcast_data (sock, message):
    for socket in CONNECTION_LIST:
        if socket != server_sock and socket != sock :
            try :
                socket.send(message)
            except :
                socket.close()
                CONNECTION_LIST.remove(socket)

def main():
    while (True):
        read_sockets,write_sockets,error_sockets = select.select(CONNECTION_LIST,[],[])
        for sock in read_sockets:
            if sock == server_sock:
                client_sock, address_sock = server_sock.accept()
                CONNECTION_LIST.append(client_sock)
                print "Client:"+str(address_sock)+" connected!"
                broadcast_data(client_sock,"Welcome to the server")
            else:
                print "Working:"

                ans = ""
                while (True):
                    msg = client_sock.recv(1024)
                    if (msg == "Hello"):
                        ans = "Hey"
                    elif (msg == "QUIT"):
                        broadcast_data(client_sock,"Bye")
                        sock.close()
                        CONNECTION_LIST.remove(sock)
                        break
                    else:
                        ans = "Error!"
                    broadcast_data(client_sock,ans)

    server_sock.close()


main()
```

Comment: I don't really see a question here. Also, what you have is a single client server. If it were a multi-client server then `server_sock.accept()` would itself be inside a loop.

Comment: @JamesKPolk
My question is how can I modify this code to be multi-client server?
What do I need to change?..

Comment: You need to `accept()` more than once. Google for "python socket server select example" if you want to see examples.

Comment: @JamesKPolk
Look at my edit please

Comment: Look at your code in that `broadcast ` function - is `socket != sock` condition ireally intended there?

Comment: @NikolaiFetissov Well I tried to delete it and it didn't solve the problem.